# How do you access a function inside an anonymous function from outside

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am writing some useful functions for my webpage for my webpage. The functions will be inside an anonymous function and will be called from outside the function. When I try to call the functions I get an error. This is how I am constructing it:

```
(function(){
    var fx ={
        pop : function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    };
    fx = window.fx;
})();
window.onload = fx.pop('hi');
```

Does anyone know how I might do this? I know this is possible because jQuery and other javascript libraries are written like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `fx = window.fx;` you are overwriting the `fx` which is in local scope of anonymous function. If you want access to it outside in the global scope you would need to do
`window.fx = fx;`. And Seems like you want to invoke the function `pop` on load and not when registering on load, Which is what you are trying to do here `window.onload = fx.pop('hi');` This will invoke `pop` immediately and set the result of method as callback for `load` event (which is undefined as your method doesn't return anything; unless the method return another function that needs to be invoked after load this becomes useless). Instead you may want to try this way.

```
window.onload = fx.pop.bind(this, 'hi'); //Now this will get invoked only after load event is completed, it bind the current context to the function pop with the argument  `hi`
```

or

```
window.onload = function(){
    fx.pop('hi'); //Now this gets invoked only after load event is completed
};
```

So you can try:

```
(function(){
    var fx ={
        pop : function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    };
    window.fx = fx;
})();
window.onload = function(){
    fx.pop('hi')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

are you *sure* jquery and other javascript libraries are written like that? I don't know of a simple way to gain access to the scope of a function, from outside that function. this seems like an unusual objective so please explain what problem you are attempting to solve with this technique, perhaps there is a more appropriate strategy.

For instance you could try:

```
var fx;
(function(){
    fx ={
        pop : function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    };
    fx = window.fx; // this will probably overwrite your previous object with undefined
})();
window.onload = fx.pop('hi');
```

Comment: Never mind, it turns out that it is supposed to be `window.fx = fx` not `fx = window.fx`

Comment: did it work after that change, *without* adding `var fx` outside the anonymous function? you should be able to avoid the scoping problem by attaching `fx` to `window`: `window.onload = window.fx.pop('hi');`